# kubectl command for finding top memory consuming pods per node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

`kubectl top pod --all-namespaces | sort --reverse --key 4 --numeric | head -10` gives top pods in a cluster. How to get top memory consuming pods per node?

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu, this is the command which works for me:

Sort by MEMORY Usage:

`kubectl get po -A -owide | grep ${NODE_NAME} | awk '{print $1, $2}' | xargs -n2 kubectl top pod --no-headers -n $1 | sort --key 3 -nr | column -t`

Sort by CPU Usage:

`kubectl get po -A -owide | grep ${NODE_NAME} | awk '{print $1, $2}' | xargs -n2 kubectl top pod --no-headers -n $1 | sort --key 2 -nr | column -t`

Comment: is there a way to either specify a specific namespace or to list the namespaces at the end for each pod?

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to sort and keep the first ten elements of the pods list per node, you can use this command:
`kubectl get po -o wide | grep <node> | awk {'print $1'} | xargs -n1 command kubectl top po  --no-headers | sort --reverse --key 3 --numeric | head -10`

Comment: It is giving an error Error from server (NotFound): pod "kube-system" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pod "kube-system" not found

Comment: kubectl get po --all-namespaces  -o wide | grep <node> | awk {'print $1'} | xargs -n1 command kubectl top po | sort --reverse --key 3 --numeric | head -10 .I had added namespace as it was asking for resource, removed --no-header as it is saying no flag --header

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide | grep <node> | grep Running | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | while read namespace pod; do kubectl top pods --no-headers --namespace $namespace $pod; done  | sort -t ' ' --key 2 --numeric --reverse
```

This checks all namespaces in case you have

This works for me on macOS where xargs doesn't accepts same paremters but should work in any *nix system

Answer (score 0):

kubectl describe node node_name will give you something like below.

```
  Namespace   Name  CPU Requests  CPU Limits    Memory Requests   Memory Limits     AGE
  ---------   ----  ------------  ----------    ---------------   -------------     ---
                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)        0 (0%)            0 (0%)            11d
                    200m (5%)     0 (0%)        400Mi (5%)        600Mi (8%)        22h
                    25m (0%)      1 (25%)       512Mi (6%)        0 (0%)            14d
                    25m (0%)      1 (25%)       512Mi (6%)        0 (0%)            14d
                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)        0 (0%)            0 (0%)            14d
                    10m (0%)      0 (0%)        0 (0%)            0 (0%)            14d
                    400m (10%)    2 (50%)       2176Mi (29%)      1Gi (13%)         14d
                    1100m (27%)   6800m (170%)  1134217728 (14%)  5073741824 (65%)  14d
                    100m (2%)     0 (0%)        100Mi (1%)        100Mi (1%)        14d
                    100m (2%)     0 (0%)        0 (0%)            0 (0%)            14d
                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)        0 (0%)            0 (0%)            14d
                    100m (2%)     400m (10%)    30Mi (0%)         200Mi (2%)        14d
                    100m (2%)     400m (10%)    200Mi (2%)        512Mi (6%)        14d
                    100m (2%)     400m (10%)    200Mi (2%)        512Mi (6%)        14d
                    110m (2%)     2010m (50%)   256Mi (3%)        1152Mi (15%)      14d
```

Comment: This shows the CPU/Memory Requests and Limits associated with the pods, which doesn't tell us anything about the actual CPU or Memory *consumption*.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
 echo <nodename>  | xargs bash -c 'kubectl get pod -A -o wide | grep $0'| awk {'print $1 " " $2'} | xargs -l bash -c 'kubectl top pods -n $0 $1 --use-protocol-buffers --no-headers'
```

Of course the

```
echo <nodename>
```

can be changed in

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Comment: sorry ...

kubectl get nodes -o name